# Which PlugIns have a [subpages] shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I'm repairing a site that was hacked a long time ago.
I have many pages that have this in them:

```
   [subpages]
```

(and I think that's called a short code).
The plugin is gone, so the page just shows the [subpages] text.

Does anyone have any idea which PlugIn(s) expands that to include
links of all the subpages?

Or - if this is a built-in feature of WordPress, then what reasons would it not be expanding to show the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found "Subpage Lister" and it solved the problem.  If there are others that use the exact same [subpages] code, then I would like to know.

https://wordpress.com/plugins/subpage-view

Now, I need to find one that supports the [previous_page]  [next_page] shortcodes. It's possible I wrote custom shortcodes and lost the code or forgot how to do them.

I found "Next Page, Not Next Post" that solved that issue.
https://wordpress.com/plugins/next-page-not-next-post